# MySQL - SUM Joined Table Column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a slightly complex query, I have almost what I need except for one one of my joins I am not getting the expected data.

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT email.*, email_type.*, email_subtype.*, email_dailytotal.*, SUM(email_dailytotal.fullconversions - (email_dailytotal.duplicates + email_dailytotal.invalids)) as validleads, email_week.*, SUM(adjustment) as total_adjustment, email_costmethod.*
FROM email 
LEFT JOIN email_type on email.type = email_type.type_id
LEFT JOIN email_subtype on email_subtype.type_id = email_type.type_id 
LEFT JOIN email_dailytotal on email_dailytotal.email_id = email.email_id 
LEFT JOIN email_week on email_week.email_id = email.email_id 
LEFT JOIN email_costmethod on email_costmethod.costmethod_id = email.costmethod
WHERE email.email_id = '12163'
AND business IN ("group", "dead") 
AND agency="MFC" 
AND start_date >="2013-02-01" 
GROUP BY email.email_id, email_dailytotal.oeyearno
ORDER BY email.email_id DESC
```

I get almost what I want except when I join `email_dailytotal` to `email`:

```
LEFT JOIN email_dailytotal on email_dailytotal.email_id = email.email_id
```

As I only get one of the rows from the `email_dailytotal` instead of all rows for that campaign.

I can do this with this basic query:

```
SELECT SUM(fullconversions) FROM email_dailytotal WHERE email_id = 12163
```

Where the result is `27` but in my overall query I get the first row which happens to be `1`.

A minimised structure of `email_dailytotal` is:

```
email_id | fullconversions  | summarydate |
```

So it contains data for each day of a campaign:

```
12163 |  1 | 2013-02-27
12163 | 10 | 2013-02-26
12163 | 15 | 2013-02-25
12163 |  1 | 2013-02-22
```

So in my join I am getting the very last row instead of a summation.

Can anyone point out where it is I am going wrong?

P.S. I apologise for the mess that is this question, I tried to make an sqlfiddle but because my build schema was over 8000 characters it wouldn't work, I have included it below if it helps anyone to answer.

I would normally show the structure of the tables but it would take me hours to format it to a reasonable standard.

**Data**

http://pastebin.com/NV0nAwrp

Comment: Please, remove all this and move it into a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: +1, I've never heard of this marvelous SQL Fiddle, it's a great idea!

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk - see my point in the question `P.S. I apologise for the mess that is this question, I tried to make an sqlfiddle but because my build schema was over 8000 characters it wouldn't work, I have included it below if it helps anyone to answer.`

Comment: @martincarlin87 Pastebin?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk done, just that I always thought it better to be in the question itself rather than just an external source.

Comment: @martincarlin87 You should post the relevant code in your question and the rest in external medium.

Comment: If it doesn't fit in fiddle then just fit what you can. Also that schema is not compact, you can insert multiple rows with a single insert statment, you don't have to repeat it for every row.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your `SELECT` clause and your `GROUP BY` clause are inconsistent.

Try changing them as follows for starters:

```
SELECT email.email_id,
  SUM(email_dailytotal.fullconversions - (email_dailytotal.duplicates + email_dailytotal.invalids)) as validleads, 
  SUM(adjustment) as total_adjustment
...
GROUP BY email.email_id
```

I also recommend using the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/02/12/why-i-use-only-full-group-by/) sql_mode so MySQL won't let you execute queries like that.